# How to start next widget that is after one ScrollVIew?

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview, mobile-application, singlechildscrollview

I have widget after the scrollview. The Tree of Widget seems like:

SingleChildScrollView:

```
    SingleChildScrollView:
    Container:
```

While scrolling i got scrolled over second scrollview only. Can't get the container. How to start the Parent scrollview after the scroll the child is completed??

Comment: Your question is a bit uncelar to me, can you eleaborate what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please share some code or show us what you are trying to achieve.